# what goes behind a float multiply a double in c++?

Tags: c++

I have some question about the precision of float multiply double using C++.

when I try the code below,

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    double x = 288144;
    float lr = 0.1;
    printf("value of lr*x = %lf \n", lr*x);
    printf("value of x*lr = %lf \n", x*lr);
    
    for (int i = 0; i<1000; ++i) {
        x = x*lr + x*(1-lr);
        printf("epoch %d, value of x*lr = %lf \n", i, x*lr);
        printf("epoch %d, value of x*(1-lr) = %lf \n", i, x*(1-lr));
        printf("epoch %d, value of x = %lf \n", i, x);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

which gives the result of

```
value of lr*x = 28814.400429 
value of x*lr = 28814.400429 

epoch 0, value of x*lr = 28814.399785 
epoch 0, value of x*(1-lr) = 259329.587334 
epoch 0, value of x = 288143.993559 
epoch 1, value of x*lr = 28814.399141 
epoch 1, value of x*(1-lr) = 259329.581537 
epoch 1, value of x = 288143.987119 
epoch 2, value of x*lr = 28814.398497 
epoch 2, value of x*(1-lr) = 259329.575741 
epoch 2, value of x = 288143.980678 

...

epoch 998, value of x*lr = 28813.757029 
epoch 998, value of x*(1-lr) = 259323.802523 
epoch 998, value of x = 288137.565992 
epoch 999, value of x*lr = 28813.756385 
epoch 999, value of x*(1-lr) = 259323.796727 
epoch 999, value of x = 288137.559552
```

as we could see, outside the loop, `lr*x` is bigger than 28814, and inside is lower.
so why does `x = x*lr + x*(1-lr)` decrease after loop and loop?
besides, if I change the code of `float lr = 0.1;` into `double lr = 0.1`, then the result of x*lr + x*(1-lr) will always equal to x.

Comment: As a rule of thumb, `float` stores precisely about 7 digits. The very first value `28814.399785` is already more digits, so assume it has some imprecision. Now after doing this math over and over you accumulate all the imprecision, which may become quite large, as you observe

Comment: With `double` the imprecision is lower, so the noticeable error might accumulate after a few thousand epochs more (or earlier/later)

Comment: This is a very general question, which requires the teaching of floating point standards. You need to understand the numerical accuracy problems introduced, and the effects of cancelation (the inaccuracy is almost certainly introduced by the "-" operation). Try reading https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loss_of_significance

Comment: `lr` is not equal to 1/10. That's the problem. Floating point arithmetic means that a recurrence relation like `x = x*lr + x*(1-lr);` is going to "go off" after a few iterations. Compute `x` from first principles on every step. Google "Patriot Missile Failure" for an example that arose due to this kind of programming.

Comment: When multiplying a `float` and a `double`, the `float` is implicitly promoted to `double`.  The resultant double is multiplied by the other `double`, giving a result of type `double`.    This is true whether `float` is the first operand of `*` or the second (i.e. whether it is to the left or the right of the `*`).

Answer (score 0):

So when multiplying a `double` by a `float`, first the `float` argument is promoted to double and then the multiplication is performed. Now in your code you have the snippet

```
x * (1 - lr)
```

in this case `1-lr` is computed such that `1` is promoted to `float`, then the subtraction is performed. After that the result is promoted to `double` in order to be multiplied by `x`. (Actually if you look at the generated assembler code, at least on my system with GCC 9.3 the `1-lr` is computed at compile time as it's a compile time constant value.)

As for the question of why `x*lr` is bigger outside the loop and smaller inside, that is because you print the result of iteration 0 *after* you update `x`.